# How to fix the problem of compose lazy layout nested crash

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to fix the problem of compose lazy layout nested crash?
I tried many methods without success.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding(),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
            SearchBar(onClick = { mainNavController.navigate(ScreenDestination.Search) }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.search_hint))
            }
        }
        item {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .statusBarsPadding(),
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(4)
            ) {
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Text(text = "test")
                    }
                }
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Text(text = "test")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't have a nested lazy scroll!!

Comment: You should take a look at [Jetpack Compose Flow Layouts](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/). Maybe that can solve your issue.